# makefile can't create .o file

Tags: c, makefile

I copied a makefile and tried to understand it and modify it to suit what I want but yet I can't configure it to run properly

I have directory hierarchy that looks like this

```
Lab2 --+ 
       |-----MyMakefile
       |    +---- makefile
       |
       |-----include
       |    +---IO.h
       |    +---matUtils.h
       |
       |-----src
            +---IO.c
            +---matUtils.c
            +---matMultp.c
```

I want makefile that exists in MyMakefile directory to compile this .c/.h files and put .o and executable files in MyMakefile directory
but everytime I run this makefile it tells me

```
gcc  -Wall -pthread -Wextra -g -Wstack-usage=1000 -fstack-usage -I -c -o MyMakefile/matMultp.o ../src/matUtils.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file MyMakefile/matMultp.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:21: MyMakefile/matMultp.o] Error 1
```

so if it's not rude to ask can anyone help me to identify the problem in it

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-Wall -pthread -Wextra -g -Wstack-usage=1000 -fstack-usage -I
LDLIBS= -lpthread
ODIR=MyMakefile
IDIR =../include
CDIR = ../src

_DEPS = IO.h matUtils.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = matMultp.o IO.o matUtils.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

_SRC = matUtils.c IO.c matMultp.c
SRC = $(patsubst %,$(CDIR)/%,$(_SRC))

all: matMultp
matMultp: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
$(ODIR)/%.o : $(SRC) $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

I've been searching for this problem for 3 hours now and couldn't find a lead to fix it :'(

I would also appreciate if someone has a good source to learn makefile

---

after MadScientist edit (if I get all the edits right so far) :

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-Wall -pthread -Wextra -g -Wstack-usage=1000 -fstack-usage 
LDLIBS= -lpthread

IDIR =../include
CDIR = ../src

_DEPS = IO.h matUtils.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = matMultp.o IO.o matUtils.o 

_SRC = matMultp.c IO.c matUtils.c 
SRC = $(patsubst %,$(CDIR)/%,$(_SRC))

all: matMultp
matMultp: $(_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
%.o : $(CDIR)/%.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

Now the error is :

```
gcc  -Wall -pthread -Wextra -g -Wstack-usage=1000 -fstack-usage  -o matMultp matMultp.o IO.o matUtils.o
    matMultp.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [makefile:18: matMultp] Error 1
```

Comment: What directory are you running this in? The `gcc` command line suggests that it's in a child directory of `Lab2` because I see `../src/matUtils.c`, but that would make it at the *same* level as the `MyMakefile` directory.

Comment: I'm currently at this level 
~/CLionProjects/Lab2/MyMakefile$

Comment: Ok, so if you're running *in* the `MyMakefile` directory, then there's no need for the makefile to refer to it as a subdirectory.  I'm not sure why the hierarchy is organized this way, I wouldn't normally expect a makefile-named directory to be used as an output place.

Comment: A complete hack to at least get stuff to compile is to go to the `MyMakefile` directory and create a subdirectory of the same name; this is where the compiler is trying to drop the output files.  The whole organization of the makefile seems a bit confused to me, but this hack would at least let you see what it's doing and perhaps adjust accordingly.

Comment: well It doesn't have to be like that,I can remove ODIR/ from (ODIR/%.o) and change the targets of matMultp to $(_OBJ) instead of OBJ

Comment: Yes you can; rewriting the makefile to assume it's already in the object directory would be a better fix.  Try it!

Comment: after I edited it, would the order of filenames .c or .o differ in meaning in _OBJ and _SRC ?

Comment: I posted the edit and the new error :\

Comment: Is there a reason you're putting your files in different directories? There can be good reasons to do this, but it's a hard way to learn makefiles. Why not put all the files in a single directory and focus on learning how *that* works, then get fancy once you understand the basics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of problems here.

If you want to learn about makefiles, the [GNU make user's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) is a good place to go.

The first one is that you are adding the `-c` option to your link line:

```
matMultp: $(_OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

This is wrong: the `-c` option tells the compiler you want to generate an object file.  Here you want to generate an executable so you should not provide `-c`.

The second thing is this pattern rule is wrong:

```
%.o : $(SRC) $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

After variable expansion, this becomes:

```
%.o : ../src/matMultp.c ../src/IO.c ../src/matUtils.c ...
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

What does this mean to make?  First, it means that if ANY `.c` or `.h` file is changed, then *ALL* the `.o` files will be rebuilt because all the `.o` files depend on all the source files.

Second, it means that *every time* make invokes the compiler it will generate the object file but always use the same source file: every `.o` file will be compiled from `$<` which is always `../src/matMultp.c`.

You need to use a pattern on the prerequisites side, so that you're compiling the appropriate `.c` file for each `.o` file and you're only recompiling the `.o` files that are out of date:

```
%.o : $(CDIR)/%.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Third, in your link line you want to link ALL the object files together, not just the first one, so you don't want to use `$<` you want to use `$^`:

```
matMultp: $(_OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Fourth, your setting for `CFLAGS` is wrong:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -pthread -Wextra -g -Wstack-usage=1000 -fstack-usage -I
```

you have a `-I` with no argument on the end of this line.  This means that when it appears in a command line, the compiler will take the NEXT option after it and treat it as the include directory name.  So in the compile line:

```
matMultp: $(_OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

it expands to:

```
gcc -Wall ... -fstack-usage -I -o matMultp matMultp.o
```

Here, the `-I -o` is treated as if `-o` were the name of a directory to search for includes, it's not the `-o` option to the compiler, so the compiler thinks that it's trying to link the file `matMultp` which does not exist.

Comment: I edited it agian after your suggestion still the same error

Comment: Most likely the problem is caused by a previous wrong compile (you have the same problem with .o files and the wrong value of CFLAGS that you had with your link line, except in that case it hid the `-c` option which means the output file, `mutMultp.o` is actually not a object file but a binary.  Please delete all the `.o` files and start from scratch.  Note that your `clean` rule is wrong because it removes all files in `ODIR`, which is not where you're putting things anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`make` doesn't create `.o` files.  It is the compiler that does it.  So as you have an option in the compiler (`-o`) to specify the output file of a compilation, you need to override the default rules of `make` in order to specify that source files and object files live in different directories.  So, for example, let's say that you have source files in `../src`, and you want your object files in `../obj`. Let's assume also that your include files are in `../include`.  First of all, you need to specify how the dependencies go, from source file to target file:

```
$(dst_dir)/%.o: $(src_dir)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

will make that, if you have an object, let's say `../obj/a.o`, then `make` will search for a file `../src/a.c` and execute (if it is newer than the target, and assuming you have `-Wall -O2` as default `CFLAGS` value)

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -o ../obj/a.o -c ../src/a.c
```

But you have to create the rule, as normal `make` has default rules to build everything without path considerations.

Second, to specify include directories, you normally use a compilation option (`-I`) that tells the compiler where to search for includes, so you need it to go in each compilation (this is easier):

```
CFLAGS = -I ../include
```

This time it is the compiler that does the compilations.  But if you need to specify the dependencies between object files and included headers, then you need to do (originally, there was a command `mkdep` to search in source files which includes were `#include`d, but now this is done by a compiler option `-M`) so you can add a rule to generate a file of dependencies and include it in the `Makefile`.

```
.depend:
    $(CC) -M >$@ $(src_dir)/*.c
-include .depend
```

or, if you have `mkdep`

```
.depend:
    mkdep $(src_dir)/*.c
-include .depend
```

#### NOTE

You have to be careful, as the later example above will process for dependencies all the `.c` files you have in the source directory, even if some of them are not used in the application.  This will rarely lead to build errors, but you can have a `.c` file not used (yet) in the application that has some preprocessing errors, and getting dependency info about that file can abort your full build because of the error.  If that is the case you can precede the command (`mkdep` or `$(CC)`) with a `-` to make the `make` command to ignore errors comming from the execution of these commands, as in:

```
.depend:
    -$(CC) -M >$@ $(src_dir)/*.c
-include .depend
```